# Find Doc Without Permissions

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I'm working on adding password reset functionality to users on my Apostrophe CMS installation. I'm using this code to find the user by email address and create a new token for later use: (in lib/modules/apostrophe-users/index.js)

```
module.exports = {
    construct: function(self, options) {
        self.route('post', 'send-reset-token', function (req, res) {
            var email = req.body.email;
            var usersModule = self.apos.modules['apostrophe-users'];
            var userList = usersMods.find(req, {email: email}, {permissions: false});
            userList.toArray(function (err, arr) {
                if (arr.length > 0) {
                    //Create token
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

But, when this request is made from a non-logged-in session (which is the point of the reset), the list of users is blank. I thought (from reading documentation) that setting the options.permissions param to false, it would get the user without checking for permissions first, but it doesn't seem to be working. I can get the user correctly when I make this call when logged in as admin.

Is there something else I need to do to find this user on the server side without the requesting person having permission to see users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second argument to `find` is the MongoDB criteria object. `permissions` is not a property of any object in the collection, so you get back nothing.

`permission` is singular and it is a cursor filter method, not a property of an options object. We don't use an options object with `find` because chainable filter methods are more flexible, documentable and testable.

What you are looking for is:

```
return usersModule.find(req, {email: email}).permission(false).toObject(function(err, user) {
  if (user) {
    // There was a user
  }
})
```

Note that `permission` is singular here.

The only place you'd find this described as part of an options object is in documentation for the old 0.5 release. The official docs for 0.5 have a big warning at the top. Let me know if you found this information on a page without a warning and I can work on getting that fixed.

Comment: Thank you! I got confused because I saw the permissions: false as part of the insert method on the doc manager. I apparently confused the parameters of find() with insert(), and since insert does take an options param that allows for permissions: false, I for some reason assumed that find did as well.

Here's the page with the insert method that allows the options.permissions flag:

http://apostrophecms.org/docs/modules/apostrophe-docs/index.html

Comment: Aha, that makes sense.